# Ruby on Rails: how can I show a variable and then exit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am still working on my small app interacting with the Steam API. I am fiddling with Nokogiri and regexps among other things and I want to output a certain variable before stopping the script. This is in a viewless action where, at the end of the process the user will be redirected to another action with a view.

I tried `puts` then `exit` but Apache hangs and I have to restart it manually. Since most of the time I want to display the variable from inside a loop, I don't want to let the rest of the script continue. Is there a way I can just show the variable's contents and the terminate the script execution from the controller? If it's not possible I could deal with logging the variable's contents before terminating the script instead of outputting it.

Comment: Could you please briefly describe your environment? Are you running one or more Thin instances behind an Apache server?

Comment: To start, you rarely, if ever, want to manually exit Rails.   This is as true in the controller as it is in the model or view.   It's not surprising that your Apache reverse proxy hangs when you do.   In fact, I'd expect exactly that behavior because you've killed off the process Apache is expecting to hand the request off to, and the request is blocked.  That's why it's hanging.   @kristjan's answer below more or less covers your two primary options for inspecting your variables inside your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in Rails, I'd recommend using [`Rails.logger`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#sending-messages) to print things out to both your server's synchronous output and your log file (in `log/development.log`, or whichever environment you're using). At that point if you want to finish your controller action, you can move on to the redirect you have planned, or cut it short and simply `render nothing: true` so you don't get output from your next action as well.

You can also pause execution and dig around in your variables using something like [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/).

Comment: I have tried using `logger.debug` which works well, however `render nothing: true` does not halt execution so if there is code below that causes an exception I still get the exception. Not that big of a deal, except it makes the log harder to read. Is there a clean way to halt execution?

Comment: `render` only sets up the HTTP response. If you want to skip the rest of your action, use `return` or other control flow logic like you would anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of `return`, thanks for reminding me!